# How can I divide the output numbers in odd and even numbers?

Tags: c++

> The output is like this
>   (odd numbers: 1even numbers: 2odd numbers: 3even numbers: 4odd numbers: 5even numbers: 6odd numbers: 7even numbers: 8odd numbers: 9even numbers: 10)

***Output should be
(odd numbers: 1 3 5 7 9, 
even numbers: 2 4 6 8 10)***

```
int main() {
  int num1,ctr=1,modu,even,odd;
  cout<<"enter a number";
  cin>>num1;

  do {
    if (ctr%2 == 0) {
      cout<<"even numbers: "<<ctr;
      ctr++;
    } else {
      cout<<"odd numbers: "<<ctr;
      ctr++;
    }
  }
  while(ctr<=num1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a container such as an array to hold the results before you print anything.  Then you print the results from the arrays.  You cannot print the results in the way you're doing it now, i.e. trying to jump back and forth between even and odd numbers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how ?

Answer (score 0):

You output all the odd number, and then set ctr as 2 and output all the even number.

Comment: No, I think this tips is enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

In doing this, you need to be careful to print the list of even numbers and odd numbers in separate loops.

I have assumed that you will have no more than 10 inputs.  If you will have more, then you need to increase the constant 'limit'.

```c++
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int limit = 10;
    int array[limit];
    int num1;
    int ctr = 0;

    while(ctr < limit ) {
        cout << endl << "Please enter a number" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
        array[ctr] = num1;
        ++ctr;
    }

    // print odd numbers
    cout << "Odd numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if(array[i] %2 == 1) {
            cout << " " << array[i];
        }
    }
    // print even numbers
    cout << "  Even numbers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if(array[i] %2 == 0) {
            cout << " " << array[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:

Odd numbers:  1 3 5 7 9  Even numbers:  2 4 6 8 10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: i jus need to enter a number and that should be ht output but thanks